# Is it a no-go to restart a user test after few seconds?

Tags: user-research, usability-testing, users

would you say it is a no-go to restart a user test with a user after few seconds because you forgot to to tell him some essential information he need to know to solve the task? Because he already got a small insight of the product and can learn from his first interactions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**This user is contaminated** and if you are looking for the first time onsite experience you should discard this user.

**But** if you are looking for all types of interaction you can use the same user multiple times.

**Pay attention**, this user could become an expert at some point and affect the final test result.